# How can I learn which method runs during a for loop?

Tags: c#, loops

I have a `for` loop, and each time through I invoke the same method. I need to find a way to learn what the previous equation was. I have to find this without using the value of incrementation. for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) { 
    checkBox[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(checkBoxMethod); }
```

Somehow `checkBoxMethod` should get the previous function in this case for instance:

```
checkBox[50].Click
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the for loop, also set the tag of each checkbox. I am assuming you are using Windows Forms here. So, here is what the modified for loop would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    checkBox[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(checkBoxMethod);
    checkBox[i].Tag = i;
}
```

Then in your event handler you can cast the sender variable to a checkbox like so:

```
void checkBoxMethod (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox)sender;
    int number = (int)box.Tag;
}
```

Whatever 'i' was at the time of creating that checkbox's event handler will be retrieved in the variable 'number' and you can use it however you want.

Comment: How will I be able to do "event handler you can cast the sender variable to a checkbox, cast the checkbox's tag property to an integer" this part? Sorry I just need a little more instructions

Comment: No problem, I clarified above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `for` loop, use recursion and pass the current count into the function:

```
void checkBoxMethod (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox)sender;
    int number = (int)box.Tag;
    myRecursiveMethod(number);
}

private void myRecursiveMethod(int count)
{
    //do whatever stuff I need to do

    if (!timeToExitTheMethod)
        myRecursiveMethod(count++);
}
```

You've given us no explanation of exactly **what** you are doing in your `for` loop and your question doesn't make a lot of sense (i.e. what are the CheckBoxes you allude to?), so I can't be very specific with my code example. Note that you'll have to code an exit point for the recursive method (otherwise it will be called until you get a stack overflow).

If you are simply looking to count the number of times a function has been called then do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _myCounter = 0;

    void checkBoxMethod (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox)sender;

        //do whatever you need to do

        _myCounter++;
    }

}
```

If you be more specific with your requirements then we can be more specific with our suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the required information to handler using lambda experssions.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int number = i;
        buttons[i].Click += (sender, args) => OnButtonClick(sender, args, number);
    }
...
    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, int number) {
        MessageBox.Show(number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
```